# Not Like in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I am new to Teradata and trying to figure out how to do a NOT LIKE statement with multiple wildcards. I've tried several different ways, but haven't found a way that works. Most recently I've tried the code below.

```
    WHERE DIAG_CD NOT IN ALL ('S060%','S340%')
```

Any help you all can provide would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. You can use ANY / ALL quantifier with LIKE or NOT LIKE.

```
WHERE DIAG_CD NOT LIKE ALL ('S060%','S340%')
```

or

```
WHERE NOT (DIAG_CD LIKE ANY ('S060%','S340%'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`IN` does not support wildcards. You need to repeat the conditions:

```
where diag_cd not like 'S060%' and diag_cd not like 'S340%'
```

Or you can do regex matching instead: `^` represents the beginning of the string, and `|` stands for *or*. This syntax is easier to extend with more strings patterns.

```
where not regexp_like(diag_cd, '(^S060)|(^S340)')
```